# R - Overlay points layer to a 3D density plot

Tags: r, plotly, overlay, point, kernel-density

I have a 3D density plot generated from x;y coordinates with the following code:

```
library(MASS)
den3d <- kde2d(data_loc$X, data_loc$Y)
persp(den3d, box=FALSE)

library(plotly)
gg<-plot_ly(x=den3d$x, y=den3d$y, z=den3d$z, type="surface") %>% 
  layout(
    scene=list(
      xaxis=list(title='X Axis (m)'),
      yaxis=list(title='Y Axis (m)'),
      zaxis=list(title='Probability density')
      ))
```

[image]

I'd like to add a points layer as in the example below :

[image]

I tried to add points with `ggplot2::geom-point ()` function  without success. I also tried the `add_markers()` function without success

Comment: I'm taking a guess that `kde2d` is from pkg:MASS. And editing the body of you Q to meet SO guidelines. You should also add a [MCVE] using the [edit] facility.